# Excel VBA: If time is between two times, add text to row, not if blank

Tags: excel, vba, time

I'm trying to add a work shift label (Day, Swing, Grave) in a particular cell in a row according to the timestamp on an entry. If there is no timestamp, I want it to do nothing.

The timestamp is formatted "hh:mm:ss" and is in the 6th/F row.

This is what I have so far. Without the 4th line it will label all entries as Day, otherwise no dice.

```
Sub Shift()
Dim Time As Date, cel As Range
For Each cel In Range("F2:F100000")
    If IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then Exit For
        If Time > TimeValue("06:00:00") And Time < TimeValue("14:00:00") Then
            cel.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Day"
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Time` is 0, it has not been assigned a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the fourth line is throwing you something unexpected, is because you have `Cell.Value`, not `cel.value`:

`If IsEmpty(cel.Value) Then Exit For`

That will fix your logic test.  Also, you need to assign `Time` something, otherwise it'll just use `00:00:00`.

Edit: I ***highly*** suggest you add `Option Explicit` to the top of your sub (or via the Excel options). This will force you to declare a variable if you are using one.  That's how I caught this error in .1 second - I copied your macro, tried to run it, and it highlighted that line right away.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine in your code. Just assign value to Time as shown below. This will take current time of the day.

`Time = DateAndTime.TimeOfDay`